# lodash: count values from array of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[
{"question":"Q1","answer":"my answer 2"},
{"question":"Q1","answer":"my answer"}
{"question":"Q1","answer":"my answer"}
{"question":"Q2","answer":"answer 2"}
]
```

I would like to group by the question keys and return the counts of each answer.

e.g.

```
{
    "Q1": [{
        "answer": "my answer",
        "count": 2
    }, {
        "answer": "my answer 2",
        "count": 1
    }],
    "Q2": [{
        "answer": "answer 2",
        "count": 1
    }]
}
```

,

I am able to `groupBy` questions using:
`.groupBy("question")` and count occurances of values using `.countBy()` but I am not sure how to combine the grouping and counting functions to achieve the desired output?

Comment: is "native javascript" approach allowed in your case?

Comment: Sure, although I am using lodash in this project would be interesting to compare how it could be done without.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start with `_.groupBy(array, 'question')` - then use `.map`

For example:

```
var arr = [
{"question":"Q1","answer":"my answer 2"},
{"question":"Q1","answer":"my answer"},
{"question":"Q1","answer":"my answer"},
{"question":"Q2","answer":"answer 2"}
];

var result = _(arr)
  .groupBy('question')
  .map(function(item, itemId) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[itemId] = _.countBy(item, 'answer')
    return obj
  }).value();

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

See the working version at: http://jsbin.com/wixoronoqi/edit?js,console

Comment: I think it would be better to use [mapValues()](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues) instead of [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map), and just return the [countBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#countBy) value directly.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `mapValues`, but yes, it would be an improvement to use `mapValues`

Comment: With ES6: `var obj = {}; obj[itemId] = _.countBy(item, 'answer'); return obj` -> `return {[itemId]: _.countBy(item, 'answer')}`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a native/vanilla js solution to this problem, using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), with and without the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

With spread operator, immutable style :

```js
const questions = [
  {"question":"Q1","answer":"my answer 2"},
  {"question":"Q1","answer":"my answer"},
  {"question":"Q1","answer":"my answer"},
  {"question":"Q2","answer":"answer 2"}
];

const groupedQuestions = questions.reduce( (g, q) => {
  return {
    ...g,
    [q.question]: {
      ...g[q.question],
      [q.answer] : (g[q.question] && g[q.question][q.answer] || 0) + 1
    }
  }
}, {})

document.write(JSON.stringify(groupedQuestions))
```

Without spread operator :

```js
const questions = [
  {"question":"Q1","answer":"my answer 2"},
  {"question":"Q1","answer":"my answer"},
  {"question":"Q1","answer":"my answer"},
  {"question":"Q2","answer":"answer 2"}
];

const groupedQuestions = questions.reduce( (g, q) => {
  typeof g[q.question] !== "undefined" || (g[q.question] = {});
  typeof g[q.question][q.answer] !== "undefined" || (g[q.question][q.answer] = 0);
  g[q.question][q.answer] += 1;
  return g;
}, {})

document.write(JSON.stringify(groupedQuestions))
```

Answer (score -2):

A "native javascript" solution using `Array.forEach` and `Array.push` functions:

```
var arr = [{"question":"Q1","answer":"my answer 2"},{"question":"Q1","answer":"my answer"}, {"question":"Q1","answer":"my answer"}, {"question":"Q2","answer":"answer 2"}];

var result = {};
arr.forEach(function(v){
    var key = v['question'], Q = this[key], found = false;
    if (Q) {
        var len = Q.length;
        while (len--) {
            if (Q[len]['answer'] === v['answer']) {
                Q[len]['count']++;
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (!found) Q.push({'answer': v['answer'], 'count' : 1});
    } else {
        this[key] = [];
        this[key].push({'answer': v['answer'], 'count' : 1});
    }
}, result);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4));
```

The output:

```
{
    "Q1": [
        {
            "answer": "my answer 2",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "answer": "my answer",
            "count": 2
        }
    ],
    "Q2": [
        {
            "answer": "answer 2",
            "count": 1
        }
    ]
}
```